# How to add text fields to mutation with files

Tags: node.js, graphql

I use graphql to upload a file.
I use this as operations field in my form-data body:

```
{ "query": "mutation ($file: Upload!) { uploadSingleFile(file: $file) { id } }", "variables": { "file": null } }
```

This as a map variable:

```
{ "0": ["variables.file"] }
```

And after that i use my file.And it works fine.But when I try adding some text fields in addition to my file, I've got this error:

```
"Variable \"$username\" got invalid value {}; Expected type String. String cannot represent a non string value: {}
```

I use the following query:

```
{ "query": "mutation ($file: Upload!, $username: String!) { signUp(image: $file, username: $username) }", "variables": { "file": null, "username": "" } }
```

and variables mapping:

```
{ "0": ["variables.file"], "1": ["variables.username"] }
```

I've got a string field as my username variable and my postman request looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApbCY.jpg

Is it possible to use files and text fields in such situation?

Comment: Sounds like you are not correctly formatting your query. Please edit your question to show the actual query you are sending, not just the error you are seeing.

Comment: have you find the solution for this @АртемДачевский